# How to sum 5 largest numbers of 6 numbers across multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a spreadsheet where we are keeping scores for golf across 6 weeks but we are only taking the best 5 scores from the 6 weeks. Each week (1-6) has its own sheet (tab)

I need to get the sum of 5 the best 6 scores. Each score is on its own sheet. (Week 1, week 2, etc.)

when I use the formula `=SUM(LARGE(C5:L5,{1,2,3,4,5}))` the result is:

> #N/A *Wrong number of arguments to LARGE. expected 2 arguments but got 7 arguments)*

Is there a different formula that will allow the "range" to be 6 different cells from 6 different sheets instead of a single range from a single sheet?

Answer (score 1):

The formula you've specified doesn't appear prima facie to correspond to the layout of your sheets as-described, but the formula on its own will not work because you are supplying an array to the 2nd argument of LARGE but haven't wrapped it in ARRAYFORMULA. If there are numerical values in C5:L5, then this will work:
`=arrayformula(sum(large(C5:L5,{1,2,3,4,5})))`